# WCF - How to handing service method returning 1 million data

Tags: wcf, memory-leaks, maxreceivedmessagesize

We have a WCF service with 4 service method & running well for last 4 years. Now client has requirement for a new service method which may return 10K to 1 million record. We have tested it with separate service and found that size of response xml is about 36MB to 200 MB and processing time it takes about 4 sec to 7-8 sec. We have made following changed in client webconfig file-

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

We have a fear that if we add this service method in existing service and changed maxReceivedMessageSize to max it may impact the memory consumption for whole service. And in case of simultaneous method call it may result out of memory kind of exception.

But client want to have this new service method in existing service. Please suggest what possible solution we can have. Client dont want to steam the information and sending as a zip file as for that they have to set up separate FTP location.

Thank,

@Niru

Comment: Its worse than you feared. You will likely get an OOM Exception simply from normal usage due to Large Object Heap fragmentation. You have got to push back on this. How I would handle this would depend very largely on the signature of the call itself, and how often the data changes.

Comment: Aron thanks. If create a new service with a new AppDomain and call this service method from within existing service method...will this resolve the problem??

Comment: That would compound the problem even more. You would have to create another copy of the data for "serialization" between the app-pools. Tell your client that its not about want or not, its about what is possible.

Comment: Arun, so you mean either we should use a separate service or if we add this method to existing service we should use stream instead of buffer to send response and in that case client will get response in file? right? please guide if you see any other possibilities. thanks

Comment: I mean it can't be done reliable in dotnet without streams.

Comment: If we use stream we have to zip the response in a file and copy to client ftp location? am i right arun?

Comment: a) No b) Why must you insist on misspelling my name?

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <!-- Create a custom binding for our service to enable sending large amount of data -->
            <binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <!-- Enable the serializer to serialize greater number of records -->
            <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication.Web.SilverlightWCFServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
    <services>
        <!-- Bind the WCF service to our custom binding -->
        <service behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication.Web.SilverlightWCFServiceBehavior"
                name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication.Web.SilverlightWCFService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBinding"
                contract="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication.Web.SilverlightWCFService"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Read this article, maybe your answer.
https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/retrieving-huge-amount-of-data-from-wcf-service-in-silverlight-application/